# DisplayTemplate for Enum not working for some values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, asp.net-mvc-5, display-templates

I have a model as enum class named Priority. I have an editor template for Priority and a display template for Enum. In the editor template, I create a dropdown listing all possible values of Priority and showing glyphicon next to the text.

The problem is, in the editor template, for the case where `(e == Model)`, the line `@Html.DisplayFor(model => e, "Enum")` will not call the display template and that option only shows the icon but not text. When I debug, it passes through that line but doesn't pass to display template. For other options, it works well.

My views and models seem like this:

Priority.cs:

```
public enum Priority {
    [Display(Name = "Low Priority")]
    Low = 1,
    [Display(Name = "High Priority")]
    High = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Critical Priority")]
    Critical = 3
}
```

Enum.cshtml (Display Template):

```
@model Enum

@if (EnumHelper.IsValidForEnumHelper(ViewData.ModelMetadata)) {
    // Display Enum using same names (from [Display] attributes) as in editors
    string displayName = null;
    var selectList = EnumHelper.GetSelectList(ViewData.ModelMetadata, Model);
    foreach (SelectListItem item in selectList) {
        if (item.Selected) {
            displayName = item.Text ?? item.Value;
        }
    }

// Handle the unexpected case that nothing is selected
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName)) {
    if (Model == null) {
        displayName = String.Empty;
    }
    else {
        displayName = Model.ToString();
    }
}

@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => displayName)
}
else {
    // This Enum type is not supported.  Fall back to the text.
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model)
}
```

Priority.cshtml (Editor Template)

```
    @model Priority

<select class="selectpicker" name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("")">
    @foreach (Priority e in Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType())) {
        <option value="@e"
                @if (e == Model) {
                    <text>selected</text>
                }
                data-icon="@{
                     switch (e) {
                         case Priority.Low:
                             <text>glyphicon-arrow-down</text>
                             break;
                         case Priority.High:
                             <text>glyphicon-arrow-up</text>
                             break;
                         case Priority.Critical:
                             <text>glyphicon-exclamation-sign</text>
                             break;
                         default:
                             break;
                    }
                }">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => e, "Enum")
        </option>
    }
</select>
```

First thing coming to my mind was caching. I removed other calls to the display template from the page but it still didn't work.